# Nginx: hide post requests in access logs

Tags: nginx

How can I  hide POST requests in NGINX access logs:

```
30/Aug/2018:11:03:31 .... method=POST request="POST /api/auth....
```

Comment: Please also consider if it is a good idea to do this, really.

Comment: This is a customer requirement, I have to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the following to your `nginx` config, as per the [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html)

```
map $request_method $loggable {
default       1;
POST          0;
}

access_log /path/to/access.log combined if=$loggable;
```

The `if` parameter enables conditional logging. A request will not be logged if the condition evaluates to “0” or an empty string. The `map` directive sets `$loggable` to 0 if the `$request_method` is `POST`

Comment: Drifter104, thank you for the answer. But Is it possible to do this without using the "if"?

Comment: @Sjoma you could do it with a different kind of `if`. This if isn't the evil kind though so you should be ok. The only other way would be if all your POST requests go to a particular url, then you could do a separate location and disable logging for all the requests in that location